# Get the DATE AND TIME data from different tables

Tags: sql

My database has three tables,

- `Studentdata` with columns `studentid , studentname`
- `Assessmentdata` with columns `studentid, attemptedondate`
- `Activitydata` with columns `studentid, date`

And each table row will be updated every day with the current timestamp.

Need help in identifying, `Mostrecentdate` column should get the date after comparing both these columns `attemptedondate` and `date` from two different tables and two different columns.

Expected output should be,

```
Studentid   studentname      mostrecentdate
 1           abc            2013-06-01 12:05
 2           def            2013-05-02 02:03
```

My current query is:

```
select 
    S.StudentId, S.StudentAccountName, 
    Max(D.attemptedondate, A.date) as MOSTRECENTTIME 
from 
    activitydata A
join 
    Studentdata S on A.StudentId = s.StudentID
join 
    Assessmentdata D on S.StudentID = D.StudentID
group by 
    S.StudentId, S.StudentAccountName
order by 
    MOSTRECENTTIME desc
```

Comment: what type are date fields?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use `CASE`:

```
select S.StudentId,
    S.StudentAccountName,
    CASE WHEN Max(D.attemptedondate) >= Max(A.date) THEN Max(D.attemptedondate) 
         ELSE Max(A.date) END
     as MOSTRECENTTIME 
from activitydata A
    join Studentdata S on A.StudentId=s.StudentID
    join Assessmentdata D on S. StudentID =D. StudentID
group by S.StudentId,
    S.StudentAccountName
```

Comment: for the above query I need help to get the list of all studentid from the table studentdata if the mostrecenttime column is null.